# How can I allow a user to upload the template for a landing page for another user in Django?

Tags: html, django, mariadb

I have the admin user able to upload via forms a landing page for a selected role (Student, Advisor, Admin) and I want to be able to get it to render properly. Right now, it renders properly the html and the css but prints out in plain text the {{ }}'s and the {% %}'s which isn't helpful.

The view for the roles landing pages as of right now sends the plain text html (`context['page'] = LandingPage.objects.get(role='adm', live=True)`) stored in the database to the html stored in templates which has nothing in it except `{{ page| safe}}`.

I can't find in the documentation any info regarding how to do this properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. This is my actual HTML file:

```
{% extends 'newscentre_base.html' %}
{% load newsletter_extras staticfiles %}
{% block title %}
  {% render_layout layout.title_block %}
{% endblock %}
{% block meta_data %}
  {% render_layout layout.meta_block %}
{% endblock %}
{% block head_scripts %}
  {% render_layout layout.head_scripts_block %}
{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
    {% render_layout layout.header_block %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% render_layout layout.body_block %}
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
  {% render_layout layout.footer_block %}
{% endblock %}
{% block footer_scripts %}
  {% render_layout layout.footer_scripts_block %}
{% endblock %}
```

I store each of the page sections inside a separate row. You don't have to do that. This is just an example. Here's my render_layout tag:

```
from django.template import Template

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_layout(context, layout_block):
    template = Template('{% load newsletter_extras staticfiles thumbnail %}' + layout_block)
    return template.render(context)
```

This is the view:

```
def newscentre_detail(request, slug):
    lookup = {'site': request.site, 'slug': slug, 'enabled': True}
    newsitem = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, **lookup)
    layout = NewscentreLayoutDetail.objects.filter(site=request.site).first()
    template = get_template("issues/public/newscentre_detail.html")
    context = {'layout': layout, 'newsitem': newsitem}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

You don't really need a tag. It's just what I used in my case. You can simply instantiate a Template class with the HTML content you fetch from the database and then use the render method and pass the context to it.

I'm not sure if that make sense :) You need this in your view:

```
template = Template('{% load newsletter_extras staticfiles thumbnail %}' + layout_block)
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Where layout_block is the HTML you got from DB.